# Lubuntu freezes less frequently than Xubuntu, which freezes less frequently than Ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, freeze

I am very new to Linux. Ubuntu would freeze so I installed Xubuntu. That would freeze less frequently, but still so. Now, I am on Lubuntu, and it still freezes although least frequently. My system is a Lenovo Thinkpad 11e. Celeron N2940 @ 1.83GHz and 8GB.

The computer freezes in day to day tasks: watching videos, browsing the web, etc. Also, the default word editor was AbiWord. I started a document on AbiWord and saved it. But after my computer froze and I restarted it, it was not able to open that document.

Comment: Please, provide more details, like Ubuntu version, Result of `free -m`, `uname -a`, etc. Are you using Disk HDD, or SSD?. This seems to be a RAM problem.

Comment: Lubuntu 16.04. Using SSD.

total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7866         400        6850         122         616        7081
Swap:          8075           0        8075

Linux name-ThinkPad-11e 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: This sounds like a hardware fault. Your computer freezes more often when it is working harder. It could be an area of RAM that is bad or even just a temperature rise that causes it.

Comment: This is definitely the c-state bug, see the second linked duplicate

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly due to a bug in the kernel with some Atom-based processors.  The workaround is to restrict the machine from going into deeper c-states.

Add `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` to the kernel arguments by editing `/etc/default/grub` and set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` so it looks something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

More details and the ongoing search for the root cause can be found in the issue at: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051

Comment: Okay, I'm not really sure what a c-state is. And I am first time Linux user and would appreciate it if you could please be a little more specific with your directions in applying the workaround.

Also, what exactly does that workaround do? I want to understand what exactly is the problem and what will fix it. I am still new and learning Linux so if this is an issue with Lubuntu and my specific CPU then I am open to learning a different distro until this issue is further researched and resolved.

Comment: C-states are states the processor enters to save power.  The higher the c-state the more power savings.  Your processor is in a family of processors that triggers this bug.  It seems that the problem is most likely a combination of a kernel bug and a processor bug.  The workaround is to not let the processor go into deeper power saving states and so it will use more power.

Comment: If you are familiar with the command line, you can disable the lower power states by editing the file /etc/default/grub and then updating the bootloader.  To do that first edit the file:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

which will open the file in a text editor.  Find the line 

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

and change it to this

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"

Then save the file using ctrl-x and answering yes to save.

then from the command line run

sudo update-grub

and reboot

Comment: Thank you I will do this. But I was wondering, does this affect every Linux distribution? I do not have this problem with Windows 10, and am still trying to wrap my head around what exactly the kernel is. So does every Linux distribution use the same kernel?

Comment: Yes, they all use the "linux" kernel.  Distributions that use older versions of the linux kernel don't seem to have this problem, but they also don't fully support the processor.